# HTML5 / JavaScript / WebGL viewer of KMZ / KML 3D OBJECTS?

Tags: html, 3d, kml, webgl, kmz

Is there any HTML5/javascript/webgl viewer of KMZ KML 3D OBJECTS ?

i would like to use WEBGL technology to render kmz/kml 3d object (building) created in sketchup and uploaded to google warehouse.

Target is to use browser technologies instead of flash/java to render 3D product overview on white backgrdound with only horizontal rotation.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: You can see an example here: Using SketchUp Models https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Using-SketchUp-Models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three.js has a [ColladaLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/loaders/ColladaLoader.js). SketchUp can export to Collada, and that's what KMZ files use. It's the .dae file in the KMZ.

Answer (score 0):

I built a small library called [kamikmz](https://github.com/HaykoKoryun/kamikmz/) exactly for this purpose. The problem with loading a Collada model straight up is that you need to have the images referenced as textures available on the correct path as well. To overcome this issue I use the [jszip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/) library to unzip the `kmz` file right in the browser and the pass it to `threejs`.

Right now the library is still in development and has some performance issues when it comes to loading large models, however it works fine for most cases.